# Can 2 different OOV words get the same vector in FastText?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, vector-space-models

Since FastText sums up the vectors(order is not considered) of an OOV word's subwords, is it possible for two different OOV words to get the same vector ? If so, then can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Theoretically it is possible, but it is unlikely.

## 1) Uncommon subwords

```
word1 = 'iiii'
word2 = 'jjjj'

word1_subwords = ['<ii', 'iii', 'iii', 'ii>']
word2_subwords = ['<jj', 'jjj', 'jjj', 'jj>']
```

In this example, there are basically `6` subwords: `['<ii', '<jj', 'iii', 'jjj', 'ii>', 'jj>']`, but these are not common subwords in general. So, there is a possibility that the embedding for *all* the subwords is the same (e.g. `[0,0,...,0,0]`), making their sum all the same.

## 2) Homographs

```
word1 = 'lie' # meaning: tell something untruthful
word2 = 'lie' # meaning: to rest on a horizontal position
```

In this example, there are two *homograph* words. These are different words but they have the same spelling. Since FastText only take syntax into account, they will have the same subword embedding sum.

Comment: If for all practical purposes, fasttext returns unique vectors, then, will incorporating subword order rather than simple summation serve any purpose?